# How can I find the networkcomms DLL, I can't find it in Github

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to create a Client Server app, and I found this [tutorial](https://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/)
I tried to download the DLL to use the lib but I can't find the DLL. Is anyone using this lib and can tell me how do I download it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://github.com/MarcFletcher/NetworkComms.Net) what are you looking for? Everything you need to know about getting started with NetworkComms.Net, including a short introduction video can be found [here](http://www.networkcomms.net/getting-started/)

You can also add it through Nuget Packet Manager using:
`Install-Package NetworkCommsDotNet -Version 3.0.3`

[Nuget Gallery | NetworkCommsDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetworkCommsDotNet/)

Comment: Hey, I've installed the package.